# Python logging solo escribe la primera vez

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando generar un fichero de log en mi app Python 3 y pese a que funciona la primera vez que ejecuto el script, las siguientes ya no escribe nada en el fichero.

Utilizo el siguiente fichero de inicio para cargar la configuración (config.ini):

```
[formatters]
keys=simple-formatter

[handlers]
keys=file-handler

[loggers]
keys=root

[formatter_simple-formatter]
format=%(name)s - [%(levelname)s] - %(asctime)s - %(message)s

[handler_file-handler]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simple-formatter
args=('C:/Python/logs/carga.log',)
maxBytes=1024
backupCount=3

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=file-handler
qualname=REST
```

Y el código en el script es:

```
fileconfig = 'C:/Python/logs/config.ini'

logging.config.fileConfig(fileconfig)

logger = logging.getLogger('REST')

logger.debug("Comienza programa")

...
...
...
```

Si el fichero de log no existe, lo genera correctamente y lo rellena con las trazas. Pero si el fichero ya existe, no pinta trazas.

No sé si el problema estará relacionado con el modo de apertura del fichero de log o tal vez haya que cerrarlo al terminar el script.